# Prefix-based multiline formatting for the class attribute in version 2.3 of prettier

Tags: tailwind-css, prettier

I just upgraded a tailwind project to Prettier v2.3 just for this feature, and for the life of me, I can't seem to find how to enable it in the documentation.
Found the blog post talking about it [here.](https://prettier.io/blog/2021/05/09/2.3.0.html#prefix-based-multiline-formatting-for-the-class-attribute-7865httpsgithubcomprettierprettierpull7865-by-thorn0httpsgithubcomthorn0) and the [PR here](https://github.com/prettier/prettier/pull/7865)

Comment: Hi, i am using prettier but it seems not doing what was mentioned [here](https://prettier.io/blog/2021/05/09/2.3.0.html#prefix-based-multiline-formatting-for-the-class-attribute-7865httpsgithubcomprettierprettierpull7865-by-thorn0httpsgithubcomthorn0)

Comment: i mean in the latest version `pretttier@2.6.2`

Answer (score 2):

My guess is your tailwind project is using JSX/TSX which uses the attribute className instead of class. Implementing this feature for the className attribute is currently being [discussed](https://github.com/prettier/prettier/issues/10663) on the prettier GitHub repo.

PS: I had the desire personally to use multi line Tailwind in my project for a couple of months so I use a tiny utility function and put it in a file named `tailwind.ts`.

```
export default function tailwind(...args: string[]) {
    return args.join(" ")
}
```

You can now do the following in any of your JSX or TSX files:

```
import tailwind from "your/file/path/tailwind.ts"

// some react function ...

<span
    className={tailwind(
        "font-semibold",
        "underline",
        "relative",
        "group",
        "cursor-pointer",
        "text-black",
        "dark:text-gray-300"
    )}
        >
// ... end of file

// Prettier will format this to the above if the line exceeds your line length
```

The advantage is that every line can now easily be commented out. The downside is that you have a lot of overhead (lot's of extra quotes and comma's + the import every time). Not sure if you like the approach, but for now it will probably have to do until Prettier implements it as well for `className`